# Python xlwings set_mock_caller not pulling through to Workbook.caller()

Tags: python, xlwings

I'm new to Python and trying to debug a script that I've written which uses xlwings. It's used to pull in function inputs from a spreadsheet front-end.

From what I've found in the documentation this seems to be the way to do debug it (in Spyder):

```
import os
from xlwings import Workbook, Range

def my_macro():
    wb = Workbook.caller()
    Range('A1').value = 'Hello xlwings!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Mock the calling Excel file
    Workbook.set_mock_caller(r'C:\path\to\file.xlsx')
    my_macro()
```

However when I run my code using the same format (from within Spyder rather than from excel vba)....

```
import xlwings as xw
def optimisation_wrapper():
    wb = xw.Workbook.caller()
    #..... my function, using input variable values from spreadsheet....
    return opto_output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mockcaller = r'\\S:.......Optimiser.xlsm' #my excel file path
    xw.Workbook.set_mock_caller(mockcaller)
    optimisation_wrapper()
```

Then I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-104-07b9dac99d09>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('S:/.../Optimiser')

  File "C:\Users\abutkovi\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 585, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\abutkovi\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 48, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "S:/.../Optimisation.py", line 210, in <module>
    optimisation_wrapper()

  File "S:/.../Optimisation.py", line 122, in optimisation_wrapper
    wb = xw.Workbook.caller()

  File "C:\Users\abutkovi\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 230, in caller
    _, xl_workbook = xlplatform.get_open_workbook(Workbook._mock_file)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Equally when I try setting a mock caller in an ipython console it comes up with the same error message.

Any advice on how to debug the script would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a problem with your file path. Change r'\\S:... to r'S:...

Also, you're defining a raw string (r'...' instead of '...'), which doesn't require escaping the '\' character.

Comment: Ah you're right, I've deleted the '\\' and it works now! Thank you so much